# sql aws athena(timestamp)

Tags: sql

how i will add 30 minutes in sql aws athena

Comment: "concat"(CAST("hour"("stamp") AS varchar), ':00 - ', CAST(("hour"("stamp") + 1 ) AS varchar), ':00') "Hours",

Comment: in place of + 1, i want to add 30 minutes, here + 1 is one hour, this query is in aws athena

Answer (score 2):

If you could provide actual source values and data type it would be easy to understand.

I am assuming `stamp` is the column name here in date time data type. Just update `now()` with `stamp` column:

```
select
substring( cast(date_add('minute', 30, now()) as varchar),12,5) as added_time,now()
```